# XMLHttpRequest returns no response & XML error

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to submit XML data using XMLHttpRequest to an external API which returns response as XML.

I have written the following code but it is not getting any response. Though I am getting 200 http response. In Firebug i get response tab empty while the XML tab shows me this error "XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal"

Can anyone please point the problem, I am running it on my local machine. Below is my complete code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;

var data;
data='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>';
data=data+'<LeadImportDatagram>';
    data=data+'<CompanyKey>302455</CompanyKey>';
    data=data+'<LeadInfo>;'
        data=data+'<Category>Gutters Drains</Category>';
        data=data+'<Subcategory>Broken Gutter Repair</Subcategory>';
        data=data+'<OfferName>First month free with one year contract</OfferName>';
        data=data+'<Contact>Graham Carpenter</Contact>';
        data=data+'<Company>Union Boxing Company</Company>';
        data=data+'<Address>34 Railroad Rd.</Address>';
        data=data+'<Address2></Address2>';
        data=data+'<City>Newark</City>';
        data=data+'<State>DE</State>';
        data=data+'<Zip>34852</Zip>';
        data=data+'<Country>United States</Country>';
        data=data+'<Phone>800-842-2345</Phone>';
        data=data+'<PhoneExt>113</PhoneExt>';
        data=data+'<AltPhone>315-342-5468</AltPhone>';
        data=data+'<AltPhoneExt></AltPhoneExt>';
        data=data+'<Mobile>315-985-4984</Mobile>';
        data=data+'<MobileExt></MobileExt>';
        data=data+'<Fax>800-842-2346</Fax>';
        data=data+'<FaxExt></FaxExt>';
        data=data+'<EMail>graham@unionboxing.com</EMail>';
        data=data+'<PotentialValue>900</PotentialValue>';
        data=data+'<Comment>We are looking for a reliable and prompt pest control provider.</Comment>';
        data=data+'<SourceCode>LEADFCTRY</SourceCode>';
        data=data+'<SourceDescription>Lead Factory Lead Distributors</SourceDescription>';
        data=data+'<SourceType>1</SourceType>';
        data=data+'<SourceClassCode>AGGREGATOR</SourceClassCode>';
        data=data+'<SourceClassDescription>Service Aggregators</SourceClassDescription>';
        data=data+'<TimeRange>9am-5pm</TimeRange>';
        data=data+'<SEligibleDate>10/1/08</SEligibleDate>';
        data=data+'<EEligibleDate>10/31/08</EEligibleDate>';
        data=data+'<LeadCost>27.00</LeadCost>';
        data=data+'<ProviderID>9843</ProviderID>';
        data=data+'<Questions>';
            data=data+'<QuestionNode>';
                data=data+'<Question>Have you previously had service done by Ace Pest Control?</Question>';
                data=data+'<Answer>No</Answer>';
            data=data+'</QuestionNode>';
            data=data+'<QuestionNode>';
                data=data+'<Question>Are you currently receiving service from any other pest control operator?</Question>';
                data=data+'<Answer>No</Answer>';
            data=data+'</QuestionNode>';
            data=data+'<QuestionNode>';
                data=data+'<Question>When was the first time you noticed your pest problem?</Question>';
                data=data+'<Answer>We first noticed the problem in July 2006 when we saw damage to one of the walls in the basement.</Answer>';
            data=data+'</QuestionNode>';
        data=data+'</Questions>';
    data=data+'</LeadInfo>';
data=data+'</LeadImportDatagram>';

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
  //xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
    alert("Ready state: "+xmlhttp.readyState)
    alert("Status: "+xmlhttp.status)
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseXML;
    } else if (xmlhttp.status==404) {
        alert("XML could not be found");
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("POST","http://www80.mypestpac.com/xml/importlead.asp",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
//xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","text/xml");
xmlhttp.send(data);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>AJAX</h2>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Request data</button>
<div id="myDiv"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>';
data=data+'<LeadImportDatagram>';
    data=data+'<CompanyKey>302455</CompanyKey>';
    data=data+'<LeadInfo>;'
```

Line 13 has to be

```
data=data+'<LeadInfo>';
```

instead of

```
data=data+'<LeadInfo>;'
```

That is causing the XML error you get.

Comment: Thanks, I have corrected that issue and now getting this error "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www80.mypestpac.com/xml/importlead.asp. Origin http://192.168.1.238 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. " Googled and found out that jsonp is one solution. But I am afraid I can't use it as it for json and not for XML response.